# CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent true don't working

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor. I want to allow the user to use all inline style that they want.

But when i use `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;`, nothing changes and ckeditor change `style` name with `[removed]`.

Here's what I've tried to do:

**config.js**

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) { };
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

I also tried:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

I cleared the cache after each change, but no luck. When I enter

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color:#ff0000">this is for test</span></p>
```

the result becomes:

```
<p [removed]="color:#ff0000">this is for test</span></p>
```

I read many articles, but still no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A simple sample on how to enabled additional markup in CKEditor

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'style;*[id,rel](*){*}'
 } );
```

extraAllowedContent here enables the  element, allows two additional attributes (in square brackets) for all (* is a wildcard) already allowed elements, allows usage of any class names (*) for them and allows usage of any inline styles { * }

To allow style tag `(style type="text/css">...</style>)`:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'style';
```

To allows any class and any inline style.

```
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*);*{*}';
```

I hope it will work for you!!

Comment: tnx for your answer , but no change. i use ckeditor toolbars to add inline css like direction and font colors

Answer (score 0):

Use CKEditor configuration file [config.js](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-using-the-config.js-file) with [allowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) property set to `true` (therefore disabling data filtering completely):

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i try that , no changes. still same problem

Comment: Did you try it exactly as I wrote it like `config.allowedContent = true;` ? Without `CKEDITOR.` in front?

Comment: @Wizard , tnx for reply, but still no change ! , ckeditor still remove style attribute

Comment: @Wizard , tnx for reply, but still no change ! , ckeditor still remove style attribute